# Handlebars if else condition multiple values

Tags: html, handlebars.js

How can I output same div in selective template?

```
{% if frame == 'frame-name-1' && frame =='frame-name-2' && frame == 'frame-name-3' %}
<div class="videoDiv">
    <button class="popupbutton" href="#popup-video-div">Click Here</button>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I'm using this code but isn't working. Can you help me? TIA!

Comment: is it possible to `frame` having three values same time??

Comment: @pradeep1991singh frame is a variable. I don't know how to simplify my code having 3 values

Answer (score 0):

One way i suggest you can register a `helper function` something like this:

Helper function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("ifvalue", function(conditional, options) {
 if (conditional.indexOf(options.hash.equals) >= 0) {
    return options.fn(this);
 } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
 }
});
```

Template:

```
{{#ifvalue possibleframes equals="frame-name-1"}}
  <div class="videoDiv">
   <button class="popupbutton" href="#popup-video-div">Click Here</button>
  </div>
{{/ifvalue}}

{{#ifvalue possibleframes equals="frame-name-2"}}
  <div class="videoDiv">
   <button class="popupbutton" href="#popup-video-div">Click Here</button>
  </div>
{{/ifvalue}}

{{#ifvalue possibleframes equals="frame-name-3"}}
  <div class="videoDiv">
   <button class="popupbutton" href="#popup-video-div">Click Here</button>
  </div>
{{/ifvalue}}
```

context:

```
{
 "possibleframes": "frame-name-1, frame-name-2, frame-name-3"
}
```

Here is output from http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

[image]

For documentation follow:

- [helper functions](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers)
- [Register helpers](https://gist.github.com/pheuter/3515945)

Hope this will help you, (y).